# KendoUI for Angular2 DataQuery toODataString not generating $filter in querystring

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

The [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dataquery/api/toODataString/) for KendoUI for Angular2 mentions that the toODataString method converts the provided state object to an oData v4 compatible string.

The structure of said state object is defined [here](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dataquery/api/State/).

I have set up a KendoUI for Angular2 grid with data-binding and server-side paging as described [here](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-binding/), which is working fine.

So now I want to add a filter object to that state, and I'm using the following code to do so:

```
private filter: CompositeFilterDescriptor;

public applyFilters(): void {
    this.filter = {
        logic: "and",
        filters: []
    };
    this.skip = 0;
    this.sort = [];

    if (this.customerNameFilter) {
        let fd: FilterDescriptor = {
            field: "name",
            operator: "contains",
            value: this.customerNameFilter,
            ignoreCase: true
        }
        this.filter.filters.push(fd);
    }
    this.service.query({ skip: this.skip, take: this.pageSize, filter: this.filter });
}
```

The service.query method then calls the toODataString method, and returns the following querystring (note the double ampersand as if it tried to insert something that evaluated to null):

> $skip=0&$top=15&&$count=true

Here is a screenshot of the debugger showing the structure of the filterDescriptor instance passed in to the toODataString method.  Please advise what I am doing wrong here?

[image: debugger showing FilterDescriptor object]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's not supported in the current beta of the toODataString method.  I looked into it's source and found there is no handling of the filter property of the state that is passed in to it.

So I rolled my own filterSerializer to append to the querystring:

```
private fetch(tableName: string, state: any, filter: CompositeFilterDescriptor): Observable<GridDataResult> {
    const queryStr = `${toODataString(state) + this.serializeFilter(filter)}&$count=true`;
    return this.http
        .get(`${this.BASE_URL}${tableName}?${queryStr}`)
        .map(response => response.json())
        .map(response => (<GridDataResult>{
            data: response.value,
            total: parseInt(response["@odata.count"], 10)
        }));
}

private serializeFilter(filter: CompositeFilterDescriptor): string {
    if (filter === null)
        return "";
    var filterString = "&$filter=";
    var filters = filter.filters.map(function (fd: FilterDescriptor) {
        switch (fd.operator) {
            case "contains":
                return "contains(" + fd.field + ", '" + fd.value + "')";
            case "eq":
                return fd.field + " eq '" + fd.value + "'";
        }            
    })
        .join(" " + filter.logic + " ");
    filterString += filters;
    return filterString;
}
```